# form renderedred into modal didn't work well

Tags: forms, modal-dialog, twig, symfony, selectize.js

I'm developing an application with symfony3. I'm using material design to customize my twig templates.

So in one of my templates, I have a hidden modal in which I'm rendering a form having a text and a select fields.

My problem is that select field didn't show the options that could be showed and that only in the modal.(if the form is rendered outside the modal it works well the problem exists when the form is rendered into the modal)

This is the link who let me open the modal :

```
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-3">
                    <div class="parsley-row"
                         style="padding-top: 22px;"
                    >
                        <div class="uk-input-group">
                            <a data-uk-modal="{target:'#modal-ajouterRue'}"><i class="material-icons md-24">&#xE146;</i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This is the modal:

```
<div class="uk-modal" id="modal-ajouterRue">
            <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
                <button type="button" class="uk-modal-close uk-close"></button>
                <div class="uk-modal-header"><h2>Ajouter une Rue</h2></div>
                {{ render(controller("GeoTunisieBundle:Rue:new")) }}


                <div class="uk-modal-footer uk-text-left">
                    <button type="button" class="md-btn md-btn-primary" onclick="newRue()">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What do I have to do?

Comment: The first thing you should do is adding the related code to let us to see how you've implemented the modal.

Comment: Thank you for replying, question updated